# Cypher query to 'expand' around a path of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two cypher queries that behave as expected.  My graph simply consists of businesses connected by relationships.

```
# Finding the shortest path that exists between two given business nodes
START a=node:Businesses('id: xxx'), b=node:Businesses('id: yyy')
MATCH a, b, p= shortestPath((a)-[*..15]-(b))
RETURN p

# Find all nodes connected 1-step out from a given business node
START a=node:Businesses('id: xxx')
MATCH (a)-[r:isRelated*]->(d)
RETURN distinct d,r
```

I now want to combine aspects of these two queries into one.  I want to find the shortest path between any two given nodes AND go 1-step out from the nodes in the returned path.  I've tried the query below which doesn't work because p is returning a path and my second match statement is expecting a node.

```
START a=node:Businesses('id: xxx'), b=node:Businesses('id: yyy')
MATCH a, b, p= allShortestPaths((a)-[*..15]-(b))
WITH p
MATCH (p)-[r:isRelated*1]->(d)
RETURN distinct p,d,r
```

How should I go about writing this type of query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
START a=node:Businesses('id: xxx'), b=node:Businesses('id: yyy')
MATCH shortest=shortestPath((a)-[*..15]-(b)) 
WITH extract(n in nodes(shortest) | id(n)) as ids
MATCH pp=(x)-->(y)
WHERE id(x) in ids
RETURN pp
```

From the shortest path you collect all node ids along and then filter in the second part. I guess this query is not very efficient, but will do the job.